# Finding the input/output representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I have a system of differential equations which can be written as $R(\frac{d}{dt})w=0$, where $$R(\xi)=\begin{bmatrix}6-5\xi+\xi^{2} & -3+\xi \\ 2-3\xi+\xi^{2} & -1+\xi\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to find the input/output representation for it.

I understand that $R(\xi)$ is supposed to be of the form $R(\xi)=\begin{bmatrix}-Q(\xi) & P(\xi)\end{bmatrix}$

So I want to find such $P(\xi)\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}[\xi]$ and $Q(\xi)\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times m}[\xi]$ which satisfy:

$\det P(\xi)\ne 0$ and $P^{-1}(\xi)Q(\xi)$ is a matrix of proper rational functions.

I can partition $w$ as $$w=\begin{bmatrix}u \\ y\end{bmatrix}$$

So that $R(\frac{d}{dt})w=0$ can be written as $P(\frac{d}{dt})y=Q(\frac{d}{dt})u$, which is the input/output representation...I'm having trouble with the first part though, attaining those two matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$ R(\xi)=\begin{bmatrix}(\xi - 2)(\xi - 3) & \xi - 3 \\ (\xi - 2)(\xi - 1) & \xi - 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

and $\det R(\xi) = 0$. So it is actually one set of equation. Assuming the correct partition of $w$ is $w = [y ~~ u]^T$ (otherwise it would be non-proper) input/output representation becomes

$$ \frac{y}{u} = \frac{1}{2 - \xi} $$

**Edit:** Let us write the equations separately:

$$ \begin{align}
(\xi - 2)(\xi - 3) y + (\xi - 3) u &= 0 \\
(\xi - 2)(\xi - 1) y + (\xi - 1) u &= 0
\end{align} $$

We need to find $y/u$ that satisfies both of the above equations. But these equations are linearly dependant, so the result follows.

Comment: Could you explain some of your steps? For instance, what do you mean 'it is actually one set of equation' and how did you derive the final input/output representation from the partition of $w$?

Comment: It means they are linearly dependant. I edited my answer, I hope its more clear now.